# How to configure pytest to import _sqlite3.so?

Tags: sqlite, pytest, shared-libraries, python-3.10

My AWS Lambda function to import .so files (so I can run SQLite with the SpatiaLite extension) works and I can run the SpatiaLite function both in local pyenv environment and on AWS lambda. However it fails locally and in the deployment pipeline when running pytest with error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

`_sqlite3.so` is stored in the root directory of the project and imported into my handler file:

```
import _sqlite3 as sqlite
```

How to configure pytest without having to set up SQLite/SpatiaLite for each environment?

Answer (score 0):

So the working directory needs to be included in the python path, so I ran my commands setting the python path to include the current working directory. e.g. `PYTHONPATH=. pytest .`

Note there will still be an issue with linking to the spatialite extension if the link library is not configured.  So you may need to run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. PYTHON_PATH=. python` to have it all work.